# Query for EAV database generates too many "null"s

Tags: mysql, sql, database, aggregate, entity-attribute-value

I have been trying for a few days to generate a query for said Entity-Attribute-Value database and I have gotten a bit rusty with sql, so even after lots of research I can't manage to get the query to do exactly as I want.

**The important parts of the table look like this:**

```
ID | concept | modifier
 1 | abc:10  | @
 2 | abc:22  | @
 2 | abc:22  | t:f
 2 | abc:78  | @
 2 | abc:78  | t:x
 3 | kfg:12  | @
 4 | aqx:23  | @
 5 | abc:49  | @
 5 | abc:49  | t:f
 5 | abc:49  | t:g
```

**I want a table like this:**

```
ID | concept | mod_f | mod_other
 1 | abc:10  | null  | null
 2 | abc:22  | t:f   | null
 2 | abc:78  | null  | t:x
 5 | abc:49  | t:f   | t:g
```

**My attempts got me already to this result:**

```
ID | concept | mod_f | mod_other
 1 | abc:10  | null  | null
 2 | abc:22  | t:f   | null
 2 | abc:22  | null  | null
 2 | abc:78  | null  | t:x
 2 | abc:78  | null  | null
 5 | abc:49  | t:f   | null
 5 | abc:49  | t:f   | t:g
 5 | abc:49  | null  | t:g
 5 | abc:49  | null  | null
```

**Here is the code that produced my result:**

```
    SELECT  t.ID, t.concept, t.modifier,
        case when t.concept LIKE 'abc:%' and t.modifier = '@' then t.concept end AS "concept",
        case when t2.modifier = 't:f' then t2.modifier end AS "mod_f",
        case when t3.modifier LIKE 't:%' then t3.modifier end AS "mod_other"
    FROM    table as t
    LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID and t.concept = t2.concept
    LEFT JOIN table as t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID and t2.concept = t3.concept
    WHERE   t.concept LIKE 'abc:%' and t.modifier = '@' and 
        (t2.modifier LIKE 't:f' or t2.modifier ='@')and 
        (t3.modifier = 't:g' or t3.modifier = 't:x' or t3.modifier ='@')

    ORDER by t.ID asc;
```

The fix looks kind of easy, but whatever I have tried reduces the results to way less than what I want (deletes too many rows basically) and at this point I don't know what I need to search for anymore.

Also the "case" part in the query looks kind of a dirty solution, that I found somewhere and used because it works (makes the "@" into "null"), so if you have a any suggestion to make the query more clean, feel free to reply.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: It is the ID and another ID, that holds the same number for each row, so didn't mention this second ID in this example.

Comment: It's always nice to see the PK. It usually gives a better idea about the structure of your data - even when there are no joins involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer and it was easier than I thought.

GROUP by is the answer. I thought this won't work for text, but you can actually aggregate the text-case select statements with *max* like this:

```
    SELECT  t.ID, t.concept, t.modifier,
        max(case when t.concept LIKE 'abc:%' and t.modifier = '@' then t.concept end) AS "concept",
        max(case when t2.modifier = 't:f' then t2.modifier end) AS "mod_f",
        max(case when t3.modifier LIKE 't:%' then t3.modifier end) AS "mod_other"
    FROM    table as t
    LEFT JOIN table as t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID and t.concept = t2.concept
    LEFT JOIN table as t3 ON t2.ID = t3.ID and t2.concept = t3.concept
    WHERE   t.concept LIKE 'abc:%' and t.modifier = '@' and 
        (t2.modifier LIKE 't:f' or t2.modifier ='@')and 
        (t3.modifier = 't:g' or t3.modifier = 't:x' or t3.modifier ='@')
    GROUP by t.ID, t.concept, t.modifier
    ORDER by t.ID asc;
```

This gets me exactly the table I was looking for. But this only works because *mod_other* can contain only 1 code per concept.